# Is there a way to catch all URLs ending in something? maybe regex match a request url, and choose to ignore it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Reason why I ask, is because there are some crawlers that plague my rails server with invalid requests.

So, I was wondering if it's possible to ignore any URL matching a regex matcher.

Like, wp-admin.php or {{.+}} or something like that?

I'm using rails 2.3.14

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want such requests reaching rails stack, so I'd suggest offloading work to your web server. However, leveraging rack middleware maybe another viable option. You can either use [3rd party code](https://github.com/udzura/rack-block) or write your own [custom handler](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html).